# RegExp for numbers 024648-4568 in dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am using Flutter and dart and I want RegExp to validate strings in the `024648-4568` like format, where a user can only put six numbers at the start, then a `-` and then 4 digits at the end.

I started with `RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}[\-]?\d{4}')`, but could not fix it for the subsequent dash and 4 digits.

In Flutter, I use it like this:

```dart
inputFormatters: [new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow( RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}-\d{4}') ,]
```

Comment: Why? What was the problem? Adding `-`? Then `\d{4}`? And the string end anchor? `$`?

Comment: Do you mean like this: RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}[\-]?\d{4}')    this dose not worked for me in Flutter.

Comment: You must add the whole relevant code to your question. And no, I clearly meant `RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}-\d{4}$')`

Comment: Did you tested that in Flutter like this: because it did worked for me, 
  inputFormatters: [new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow( RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}-\d{4}') ,], with your solution I can not write any input

Comment: *A TextInputFormatter that prevents the insertion of characters matching (or not matching) a particular pattern.*  - the validation triggers for each input char, right? That is why it can't work in general. Try a regex that matches all of these as optional chars except the first digit, `RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}(?:-\d{0,4})?$')`

Comment: Or, `RegExp(r'^\d{0,6}(?:-\d{0,4})?$')`

Comment: These two worked well, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the regular expression you use in the `FilteringTextInputFormatter` can match a zero- or one-char length string. For example, you can use

```dart
RegExp(r'^\d{1,6}(?:-\d{0,4})?$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryZNZe/1). The `{1,6}` limiting quantifier makes the first digit required in the input.

*More details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,6}` - one to six digits
- `(?:-\d{0,4})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d{0,4}` - zero to four digits
- `$` - end of string.